# How to tell if the hidden text layer in a pdf file is from OCR or not?

Tags: pdf

I have seen some pdf files after OCR have very accurate text (both in terms of recognition rate, and in terms of alignment of text to the image).

What Unix/Linux tools help me tell, if the hidden text layer in a pdf file is from OCR or not?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Unix or Linux.

Comment: It is on topic, because it is about how to do that using applications running under Unix or Linux, not on other OSes.

Comment: @tim - I've removed that link since that's a copyrighted book and should not be shared here. Find another example. In the mean time I'm closing this as off-topic. This seems to be a better question for the tex site, potentially.

Answer (score 4):

The only images in that file are the front and back covers, the rest is normal  text, not hidden behind a scanned image.

Another indication that this is typeset text and not OCR-ed is that special font characters are correct selectable despite their font and them being typeset as e.g. superset and also text in images where OCR normally gets confused.

Additionally `pdfinfo` indicates that the file is Created by DVIPSONE, i.e. that it is a (La)TeX file -> DVI -> PS and then converted by Distiller 4.05 for Windows to the PDF file. It is unlikely that a PDF file constructed from scans would have DVIPSONE as a creator

Comment: Another indication is that at 4.5 MB and 704 pages, the file is *far* too small in size to be an image-based PDF. Even highly compressed 1-bit images at reasonable resolution (200-300 dpi) are often 100 KB or more per page which would put us in the neighborhood of a 50-100 MB PDF.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That's right. You would more expect that from a DjVu file of a scan.